# rxJava: Run the code only if all Flowables was consumed

Tags: rx-java

I have two FLowable objects.
I need to execute some code, when all of them are consumed.
Besides, i need to execute code when any of Flowables updated.
I do not need any map function to be executed(do not need them).

I have tried to use something like code below

I think this is very very wrong to do like that

```
Flowable<User> user = mDataRepo.getUser();
Flowable<Goal> goal = mDataRepo.getGoal();
Disposable userDisposable = user
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(user -> {

            Disposable goalDisposable = goal
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(goal -> {

                        // do my things with user and goal

                    }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
            mDisposable.add(goalDisposable);

        }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
mDisposable.add(userDisposable);
```

Here is an example of non Rx

```
mData.getUser(new AppDataSourceOld.GetUserCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onUserLoaded(@NonNull User user) {

        mData.getActiveGoal(new AppDataSourceOld.GetGoalCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLoaded(@Nullable Goal goal) {

                // do my things with user and goal

            }
        });

    }
});
```

**Edited:**

Solution inspired by @akarnokd

```
Flowable<User> user = mDataRepo.getUser();
Flowable<Goal> goal = mDataRepo.getGoal();
user.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .zipWith(goal, new BiFunction<User, Goal, Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object apply(User user, Goal goal) throws Exception {
                // do my things with user and goal

                return 1;
            }
        })
        .subscribe();
```

This looks better. But! I need to return something. Because result of `zipWith()` must not be null, if it is - i receive `java.lang.NullPointerException: The zipper returned a null value`

So, that does not seems ideal to me, and i think i'm missing something.

Comment: Sounds like a typical case for `merge` followed by `doOnNext` for each new item from any of them and `doOnComplete` when all has been merged.

Comment: @akarnokd Thanks for comment! But how do i get two different objects in `doOnComplete()` ? The thing is, i need to user global vars to combine result

Comment: What do you mean by getting two different objects? If the sequence terminate, there are no more items to do anything with.

Comment: @akarnokd The thing is, i need to have both objects(User and Goal, see my code). Not separate them by `doOnNext()` for each of them.

Comment: Try `user.zipWith(goal, (u, g) -> ...)`.

Comment: @akarnokd Please, see my edits

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187861/discussion-between-serhii-pokrovskyi-and-akarnokd).

Answer (score 0):

Actually i think you need to use `Flowable.combineLatest()` instead of `.zip`. As zip doesn't fit you request "Besides, i need to execute code when any of Flowables updated". 
So you'll have something like:

```
Flowable.combineLatest(user, goal, { u, g -> 
    // do my things with user and goal
    return 1;
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe()
```